# SIM800L CIPSEND error, cannot make requests

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command, gprs, sim900

I am trying to connect to internet via the SIM800L module, I tried several things but I end up having an error in the CIPSEND command, I tried without specifying the amount of characters but still the same issue.

Previously I was able to execute CIPSEND but could not go further because I could not send the ctrl+z command to finalize, but I cannot remember the sequence I used at the time.

Is there anything wrong with what I am doing? may I need any other command?

```
AT+CGATT=1
OK

AT+CIPMUX=0
OK

AT+CSTT="antel.lte","",""
OK

AT+CIICR
OK

AT+CIFSR
10.65.70.197

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.google.com",80
OK

AT+CIPSEND=119
ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it fixed, clearely posting it to stackoverflow worked, because I'be been working on it for 2 days and now in 20 minutes worked haha.

For everyone having a similar issue, The problem is that I had connected both of the antennas that come with the device, de spiral wire one and the pcb with the cable, even tough I was getting IP and everything (being able to call and sms) the data connection did not work.

I removed the wire antenna and left only the PCB one.

Another thing that may cause issues is an unstable supply for the sim800l module. If you have the cheap one that does not include voltage revulator (3.8 - 4.2v) remember to add capacitors to the external regulator.